# MYSQL: Help Querying Results From Three Tables

Tags: mysql, join

I am wanting to query results from two "content" tables and one "users" table.

The two primary content files have identical field names, yet different fields - as one of the tables is for comments made by registered members and the other for comments by guests.

Consider the "widgetID" to be the primary IDentification of the widget for which I am trying to loop through the comments. Likewise the "active" is a 0 or 1 for whether it has been approved to be viewable.

table_widget:
id
datetime
usersID
message
active

table_member_comments:
id
datetime
widgetID
usersID
message
active

table_guest_comments:
id
datetime
widgetID
usersName
UsersEmail
message
active

table_users:

id
datetime
usersID
fullName
active

So what I have been trying to figure out is how to query both tables together to end up with one result with which to loop and display both the members and public comments.

I am pretty sure I need to do a JOIN, and I have tried and failed to wrap my head around the correct procedure.

I need to do the initial SELECT ... with the JOIN in here that I am not getting... WHERE widgetID = ? AND u.active = '1' ORDER BY DateTime DESC LIMIT 0, 100

Its the darn part in the middle that is tweaking me up here. Would love to have somebody show me how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: I believe what you want is a `UNION`, not `JOIN`...

Comment: Yeah, that was clearly where I was getting all messed up. Thanks. I will accept the one from Steve has he answered it first. I will upvote both answers and they are both correct. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A join isn't the best option here, you need to use UNION which will combine data not join it together.

For example:

```
SELECT mydata.message FROM
(
SELECT datetime, message FROM table_member_comments WHERE widgetID = 100 AND active = 1
UNTION ALL
SELECT datetime, message FROM table_guest_comments WHERE widgetID = 100 active = 1
) mydata
ORDER BY mydata.datetime ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION` to tack on the results from another query onto the same result set:

```
SELECT   a.*
FROM     (
         SELECT c.message, c.datetime, u.fullName
         FROM   table_member_comments c
         JOIN   table_users u ON c.usersID = u.usersID
         WHERE  c.widgetID = ? AND c.active = 1

         UNION ALL

         SELECT message, datetime, usersName
         FROM   table_guest_comments
         WHERE  widgetID = ? AND active = 1
         ) a
ORDER BY a.datetime DESC 
LIMIT    0,100
```